# Is there a way to close Bootstrap modal without call the hidden handler

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I use [Bootstrap3 Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). I bind the 'hidden.bs.modal' with a handler, but in a special case I need to just close modal without call the hidden handler, after that, next time user open the modal and close it again, then hidden handler get called as normal:

```
//suppose modal is shown, unbind first to prevent the handler run
$('..').unbind('hidden.bs.modal');
$('..').modal('hide');
//rebind the handler
$('..').bind('hidden.bs.modal',function(){//...});
```

But seems not to work: it still calls the handler.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried hiding it first then unbinding? calling .modal('hide') on the element attaches the event again after you just unbound it.

$('..').modal('hide');

$('..').unbind('hidden.bs.modal');

$('..').bind('hidden.bs.modal',function(){//...});

Comment: Tried but no luck, as i said what i want is 'just hide modal without call the hidden handler', but next time when you open the dialog and hide it, it will call hidden handler as normal.

Comment: I might not be understanding the scenario. can't you just use $('..').hide(); ?

Comment: Use $('..').hide(); did hide the dialog, but leave the black background there and I can't interact with the page again.

Comment: it's a bit "hackish" but you can just .hide() that element as well.

Comment: Yes I can hide the modal and the background completely but next time it can not open.

Comment: if you've used .hide(), then you have to use .show() the next time. not sure why you'd want this kind of behavior (as it's hackish) and not just use the modal's default hide behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt same problem earlier and used this hackish to prevent calling hidden callback in some cases. hope it will help you

```
function close_modal_without_callback() {
      $('#myModal').off('hidden.bs.modal');//`off` to remove event handler attached with `on`
      $('#myModal').modal('hide'); // hide modal
      setTimeout(function() { //to add little delay to reattach the event
            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
                     hidden_handler(); //handler function 
            });
       }, 1000);
 }
```

Comment: Your hack just works almost perfect, I just forget to try the timeout method before...Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome! How cloud i imagine that .off exists?!?! THANKS!